# Running Windows on a virtual machine vs running it on a PC

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, fedora, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am wondering what is the difference between running Windows on a virtual machine vs running it "normally" on the PC? I am wondering if I lose some functionality by not dual-booting Windows/Fedora and instead run Windows on a virtual machine in Fedora (nice to not have to reboot to go into Windows).

To answer my question partly then I have already faced an issue with virtual Windows that I did not face on my Windows laptop but then I was running it on VirtualBox, hypervisor type 2, and it seemed like I could make virtual port pairs work in the virtual Windows and when I ran PicSimLab wasn't fully functioning.

So to narrow my question - if I run a hypervisor 1 type virtual machine (i.e. hyper-v), do I lose some functionality?

Comment: If you have a decent computer with a fast (NVMe) SSD drive, the full Windows installation as a VM should work fine